# nginx returning netstring with wrong length?

Tags: nginx, scgi

I installed nginx (`nginx version: nginx/1.7.9`) via macports on my mac running the latest OSX.

I configured a URI to use SCGI:

```
location /server {
    include /Users/ruipacheco/Projects/Assorted/nginx/conf/scgi_params;
    scgi_pass unix:/var/tmp/rpc.sock;
    #scgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

And when I do a GET request on `127.0.0.1/server`, I see the following on my SCGI server:

> 633:CONTENT_LENGTH0REQUEST_METHODGETREQUEST_URI/serverQUERY_STRINGCONTENT_TYPEDOCUMENT_URI/serverDOCUMENT_ROOT/opt/local/htmlSCGI1SERVER_PROTOCOLHTTP/1.1REMOTE_ADDR127.0.0.1REMOTE_PORT62088SERVER_PORT80SERVER_NAMElocalhostHTTP_HOST127.0.0.1HTTP_CONNECTIONkeep-aliveHTTP_CACHE_CONTROLmax-age=0HTTP_ACCEPTtext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8HTTP_USER_AGENTMozilla/5.0
>   (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115
>   Safari/537.36HTTP_DNT1HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODINGgzip, deflate,
>   sdchHTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGEen-US,en;q=0.8,End of file

The problem is that the length of the netstring, 633, does not match the interpretation. If I understand the netstrings [spec](http://cr.yp.to/proto/netstrings.txt) correctly, 633 should be the length of characters between the first `:` and the last `,`:

> Any string of 8-bit bytes may be encoded as [len]":"[string]",". Here [string] is the string and [len] is a nonempty sequence of ASCII digits giving the length of [string] in decimal. The ASCII digits are <30> for 0, <31> for 1, and so on up through <39> for 9. Extra zeros at the front of [len] are prohibited: [len] begins with <30> exactly when [string] is empty.

For example, the string `hello world!` is encoded as `31 32 3a 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21 2c`, i.e., `12:hello world!,`.

So, I'm getting the wrong length. How can this be explained?

Comment: You should consider trying to move SCGI server to virtual machine and take tcpdump to see exactly what nginx asks from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your example response has correct length.

According to example here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Common_Gateway_Interface

Field values are preceded and followed by <00> symbol (ASCII symbol with hex code 00), eg.:

```
REQUEST_METHOD <00>GET<00>
```

Once I added missing spaces to your response snippet – it quickly got back to 633 bytes, as advertised.

I suppose somewhere in the process of passing that response to us here, some piece of software stripped <00>'s, which is a totally normal behaviour?

Anyway, the answer seems to be – your nginx is either returning a correct length, or your response is stripping <00>'s somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Well,

The hexadecimal `<31 32 3a 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21>` 
in `ASCII` is `"12:hello world!"` (no quotes) and the lenght is 12 (hello world!)

And this one `<31 32 3a 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21 2c>` in the example *is wrong* (at least it didnt match the nginx norm.)(since the internal lenght is 13 and the lenght specified in hex is 12):

The ASCII `"12:hello world!,"` should be `"13:hello world!,"` and in hex `<31 33 3a 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21 2c>`

This line is the mess:

> For example, the string "hello world!" is encoded as <31 32 3a 68 65
>   6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21 2c>, i.e., "12:hello world!,".

```
OK) 12:hello world!  ---> <31 *32* 3a 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21>

KO) 12:hello world!, ---> <31 *32* 3a 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21 2c>

OK) 13:hello world!, ---> <31 *33* 3a 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21 2c>
```

The hex inside the ** is the second number of the lenght.

Then your concept about this Ok, the example is bad.

Comment: But nginx is returning a very different number.